# how to display the UIButton and UITableview in ios6&ios7 for 4-inches screen and 3.5 inches screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I am developing an app. In the app I wrote the code for a 3.5-inches screen and 4-inches screen for ios7&ios6. I took one view controller; in this view controller I want to display two images, one for the top and another for the bottom.And also display login and logout buttons and login Tableview. On the ios7&ios6 3.5-inch screen and 4 inches screen there is no problem with the display the two images like Top image and Bottom image. The two images are  displayed properly.But button and UITableview not displayed.I cant understand where is the  problem for displaying UIButton and UITableview. Please give me ideas, anyone. I am new to programming. Thanks in advance.

The below is my code.

Viewcontroller.m (3.5 inches and 4-inches screen for ios7 & ios6).

```
 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)  
  {

   if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {

     imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 65, 162, 57)];

     imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 415, 300, 153 )];

     // Button Login for ios7 4-inches screen.

     btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(20, 230, 127, 32);

     // Create Login for UITableview

     tableVw=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 123) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

  }

  else
   {

   imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 45, 162, 57)];

   imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 395, 300, 153 )];

   // Button Login for ios6 4-inches screen.

   btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(20, 230, 127, 32);

   tableVw=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 123) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    }

   imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];

   [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];

   imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-02.png"];

   imgBuilding.alpha=0.4;      

   [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];

   btnLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

   [btnLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(login) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

   [btnLogin setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sign-in-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [self.view addSubview:btnLogin];

   // create Login tableview properties

   tableVw.dataSource = self;       
   tableVw.delegate = self;

   tableVw.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

   tableVw.scrollEnabled=NO;

   tableVw.scrollsToTop=NO;

   [self.view addSubview:tableVw];

 }
```

/********************************************************************************************************/
    /********3.5 inches screen for ios6 and ios7********************************************************/

/********************************************************************************************************/

```
 else
 {

  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
   {

    imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 70, 162, 57)];

    imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 345, 320,140 )];

    btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 127, 32);

    // create Login Tableview

    tableVw=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 85, 300, 123) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

   }

   else
   {

    imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 162, 57)];

    imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 325, 320,140 )];

    btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 127, 32);

    tableVw=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 85, 300, 123) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

   }

   imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];

   [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];

   imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-02.png"];

   imgBuilding.alpha=0.4;

   [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];

   // Create Button Properties

   btnLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

   [btnLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(login) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

   [btnLogin setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sign-in-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [self.view addSubview:btnLogin];

   // Create Login Tableview properties

   tableVw.dataSource = self;     
   tableVw.delegate = self;

   tableVw.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

   tableVw.scrollEnabled=NO;

   tableVw.scrollsToTop=NO;

   [self.view addSubview:tableVw];


   }

  }
```

Comment: Add Statement like btnLogin = [UIButton alloc]init]; above the if. And change type from roundrect to custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. i made changes in your code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    UIImageView *imgLogo;
    UIImageView *imgBuilding;
    UIButton *btnLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UITableView *tableVw;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7){

            imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 65, 162, 57)];
            imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 415, 300, 153 )];

            btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(20, 230, 127, 32);

            tableVw=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 123, 320, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        }else{

            imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 45, 162, 57)];

            imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 395, 300, 153 )];



            btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(20, 210, 127, 32);

            tableVw=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 103, 320, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        }

        imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];
        imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
        imgBuilding.alpha=0.4;
        [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];

        [btnLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(login) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [btnLogin setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:btnLogin];

        tableVw.scrollEnabled=NO;
        tableVw.scrollsToTop=NO;
        tableVw.dataSource=self;
        tableVw.delegate=self;
        [self.view addSubview:tableVw];

    }else{

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7){

            imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 70, 162, 57)];
            imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 345, 320,140 )];

            btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(20, 230, 127, 32);

            tableVw=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 127, 300, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        }else{

            imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 162, 57)];
            imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 325, 320,140 )];
            btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 127, 32);

            tableVw=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 85, 300, 123) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        }

        imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];
        imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
        imgBuilding.alpha=0.4;
        [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];

        [btnLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(login) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        btnLogin.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [self.view addSubview:btnLogin];

        tableVw.dataSource = self;
        tableVw.delegate = self;
        tableVw.scrollEnabled=NO;
        tableVw.scrollsToTop=NO;
        [self.view addSubview:tableVw];
    }

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%D",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text=@"1";


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: And @user2930730 try this code and if it solves your problem please accept it. so another user can use it.

Comment: @Thanks for your response brother.Thank u so much

Comment: its my pleasure to help